# I forgot my username and password

Tags: google-account, account-recovery

I have forgot the username and password, how to reset for all even though I enter the back up email

Comment: go to forget password,option. ..... verify your mobile number and get password. ......

Answer (score 1):

From Google Help page [Recover your username and password](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/41386?hl=en):

> If you ever forget your sign-in information, you can go to Google's [password assistance page](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/) for help.

As you don't remember your username, first select the second option `I don't know my username` and click on `continue` and follow the instructions.

Once you know the username you can recover your password by selecting the first option `I don't know my password`.